# How to don't validate fields that don't exists in Schema object

Tags: joi

I have a schema with two fields, but in some cases is necessary send other field that not is necessary validate. How to allow this fields?

```
const schemaInsercao = Joi.object({
    nome: Joi.string()
        .min(3)
        .max(255)
        .required()
    ,
    ativo: Joi.string()
        .max(1)
        .required()
        .valid('S', 'N')
    ,
    descricao: Joi.string()
        .max(255)
        .required()
});

....

sending 

{
    "nome":"Invictos Tecnologia",
    "ativo":"S",
    "teste":""
}

the error

{
    "msg": "\"teste\" is not allowed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#anyvalidatevalue-options

```
schema.validate(data, {
  allowUnknown: true
})
```